# Iterating through datagrid gives an error: "Unable to cast type"

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid which i populate using these codes:

```
public class items
{
    public string prfNo { get; set; }
    public string mrsNo { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public string uom { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public string remarks { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string purp { get; set; }
    public string approvedBy { get; set; }
    public string dateApproved { get; set; }
    public string preparedBy { get; set; }
    public string datePrepared { get; set; }
}

private void fillDatagrid()
    {
        if (chkNewItem.IsChecked == true)
        {
            purpose = "NEW ITEM";
        }
        else if (chkStock.IsChecked == true)
        {
            purpose = "STOCK";
        }
        else if (chkOthers.IsChecked == true)
        {
            purpose = txtOthers.Text;
        }

        ObservableCollection<items> itemData = new ObservableCollection<items>()
        {
            new items()
            {
                prfNo  = txtPRFNo.Text,
                mrsNo = txtMRSNo.Text,
                itemName = txtItem.Text,
                qty = txtQty.Text,
                uom = txtUOM.Text,
                model = txtModel.Text,
                brand = txtBrand.Text,
                remarks = txtRemarks.Text,
                status = txtStatus.Text,
                purp = purpose,
                approvedBy = txtApprovedBy.Text,
                dateApproved = txtApprovedDate.Text,
                preparedBy = txtPreparedBy.Text,
                datePrepared = txtPreparedDate.Text
            }
        };

        dgItems.ItemsSource = itemData;
    }
```

and i want to insert the data from datagrid to database table.
I tried iterating through datagrid using:

```
foreach (DataRowView dr in dgItems.ItemsSource)//ERROR HERE
{ }
```

but it gives me an error : "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'items' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your ItemsSource contains collection of "items" and you have declared it as "DataRowView" in foreach loop.

Use it like this:

```
foreach (items dr in DataGrid1.ItemsSource) //ERROR HERE
{
}
```

OR

```
foreach (var dr in DataGrid1.ItemsSource) //ERROR HERE
{            
}
```

Comment: items dr worked for me! Thanks sir!
but i have new problem, I cannot insert multiple data in Datagrid.